# break each() function iterating over hash in Perl

Tags: perl, hash, each, break

I am using a while loop to go over a hash. Within that while loop, I want to be able to terminate the loop from within. The code below works in terms of stopping looping, but when the code is executed again the next time (it is inside a larger loop), the loop continues where it was broken off. I guess I need to somehow reset the each function, but I am not sure how to do that.

```
my $break = 0;
while (!$break() and (($key,$value) = each %ENV)) {
    print "$key=$value\n";
    if ($key eq "stop") {
       $break = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: `keys %ENV;` before the `while` loop. Also, worth mentioning http://blogs.perl.org/users/rurban/2014/04/do-not-use-each.html

Comment: FWIW: Not really what you're asking about, but the uses of `$break` might be replaced with `last if ($key eq 'stop');`

Comment: normally true, but actually I am using it within yet another loop that I would also nee to break, so my $break flag does make sense

Comment: @user1769925 - to break out of an outer loop, use can put a label at the start of the loop and call `last LABEL`